# Spring Integration - Exceptions and retries

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-retry

**My setup:**
I have a message daemon using ActiveMQ which will consume JSON messages.
The publisher of JSON messages adds `type` header with value, for ex, `com.example.Foo` which is the type of the json message. I use this to transform json to pojo.

**Spring config:**
Once the message is received, these are the steps it goes through:
1. Transformer: Transforms json to pojo
2. Payload type router: Based on the type of the pojo, routes the pojo to appropriate service activator.
3. Service activator: Process the message.

```
<int:chain input-channel="transformerChannel">
    <int:transformer id="jsonToPojoTransformer" ref="JsonToPojoTransformer" method="transform" />

    <int:payload-type-router default-output-channel="defaultChannel">
        <int:mapping type="com.example.Foo" channel="fooHandlerChannel"/>
        <int:mapping type="com.example.Bar" channel="barHandlerChannel"/>
    </int:payload-type-router>
</int:chain>

<int:service-activator input-channel="fooHandlerChannel" ref="fooHandler" method="onMessage"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="barHandlerChannel" ref="barHandler" method="onMessage"/>
```

Service activator definition:

```
public class FooHandler {
    public void onMessage(Foo foo) {...}
}
```

**Problem:**

1. I want to know how to access the message headers in the service activator. It seems like the service activator does not have access to the message headers since the transformer is returning a pojo.
2. Lets say the service activator is unable to call a down stream rest service for whatever reason. I want to skip processing this message now and I want to retry this message later. Or lets say there was an exception in processing this message. I want to retry processing this message after some delay. How do I accomplish this?

--edit--
Removed details to reduce question size as per Artem's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try do not make so long topics here in SO. It's hard to answer particular question if there are to many of them.

Absolutely not clear why you can't get access to header from your service activator method. You can accept the whole `Message<>`, and call its `getHeaders(). You can use`@Headers`annotation on the`Map`arg to get headers from the message. You can use`@Header` annotation to extract exactly particular header from the message.

Even if your transformer method returns just a POJO that doesn't mean that it isn't wrapped to the `Message` with the headers from requestMessage. If you need to return specific header alongside with your POJO, you should create `Message` yourself, using `MessageBuilder` and don't forget to copy requestMessage headers, just because transformer doesn't copy request headers if the whole message is returned.

You have to support TX on your JMS consumer, so that `RuntimeException` will lead to the rollback and, therefore, redelivery eventually. And you should ensure that all the flow is performed in the same thread. Otherwise TX is committed and message is acked on the broker. The same happens when you don't have transactions.

Comment: My service activator was defined as `public void fooHandler(Foo foo) {...}`. Hence I was wondering how to access the headers. I changed it to `public void fooHandler(Message<?> message) {...}`. Now the payload has an instance of `Foo` and the message headers are available. I wasnt aware that what transformer returns is also wrapped in `Message`.

And I added more details to explain why I was doing what I was doing. Many times people ask why I chose a particular way of doing something. Hence the detailed long message.

Comment: OK. Maybe that is just effect of the evening :-). Is my answer useful or do you need anything else?

Comment: I am trying to find spring documentation regarding the tx on the consumer side. Can you point me to the right documentation? I'm still searching through the massive spring integration reference.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-message-driven-channel-adapter which is fully based on the http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-tx